# display files from onedriver in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I use iframe to view files from onedriver on my web app php.

it works fine before, but recently I can not, I have tried many ways but no result

This is code for my file php

```
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=ca91cd81c0fee9e6&resid=CA91CD81C0FEE9E6%21262&app=Word&authkey=%21AJHFjDm4aQXDEb4&wdo=1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I was wrong place, everyone helps me!

Answer (score 0):

On the document, right click and select: "embedded".
It will generate an iframe for you.

[More information](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-online-help/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-blog-HA102029502.aspx)